# Flexbox layout, wrapping issues

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to build a layout with large and small blocks.

The issue I am having is that I want block 4 and 5 to sit underneath 2 and 3. But in my fiddle they go on to a new line.

How can this be achieved?

```css
.blocks{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
li{
  width: 25%;
}
li.large{
  width: 50%;
}
img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="blocks">
  <li class="large"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
  <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: don't think you can do that without editing your markup and put in nested flexboxes

Comment: could you show me an example?

Comment: Do you really need to use flex? Simple floats would do nicely for this example with images.

Comment: Could you show me a float example?

Comment: Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/agsc6zhu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need change HTML structure and wrap small `li's` in another `li > ul`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
  flex: 1;
}
ul ul li {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="blocks">
  <li class="large"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
      <li><img src="http://placehold.it/350x250"></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```